# Joining two dataframes by different values | Plotting two dataframes in one plot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have this dataframe:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Full.Name            Year       freq     Ra
  <chr>                <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A. Patrick Beharelle 2019   0.000713  0.110
2 A. Patrick Beharelle 2020  -0.0946   -0.116
3 Aaron P. Graft       2019   0.835     0.276
4 Aaron P. Graft       2020  -0.276     0.376
5 Aaron P. Jagdfeld    2019  -1.20      0.745
6 Aaron P. Jagdfeld    2020  10.7       0.889
```

Which describes a certain topic. Now, I want to visualize the freq column by Full.Name with a plot. That's not that hard. I can do that. But here comes the tricky part, which I am not able to do:

**I have another dataframe, which is exactly the same structure (same columns, but different values), dealing with another topic and I want to include this dataframe into the other one's plot so that I can compare them.**

I tried merging both dataframes, but both dataframes have a different amount of observations, therefore it' hard to merge. I tried to `innerjoin()` but due to the values of Full.Name not matching, that was not successful for me. Maybe there is another way to join both dataframes.

Any suggestions how to include both dataframes into one plot or even some kind of merged table, distinguishing between both topics, would be great. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, .id = "source")` would give you a table in long form combining tables df1 and df2. Then you could filter to identify mismatches, or use pivot_wider to display the values side by side. Is there any way you could provide specific sample data that we could run, and explain how you specifically want to compare them?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your problem is that you have two dataframes and you want to compare the values in those two dataframes using one plot. You can achieve that by appending those two dataframes. Here is an example below:

```
## Sample DataFrame1
df1 = data.frame(Names=c("Alpha","Alpha","Rome","Victor","Victor"),
                 Year=c(2019,2020,2019,2020,2019),
                 Freq = c(0.000713,-0.000713,0.01724,-0.0760713,0.00213),
                 Dataframe="df1")

## Sample DataFrame2
df2 = data.frame(Names=c("Gamma","Gamma","Tango","Pan","Beta"),
                 Year=c(2019,2020,2019,2020,2019),
                 Freq = c(0.0713,-0.090713,0.1724,-0.013,0.0299),
                 Dataframe="df2")

## Appending the two DataFrames
rbind(df1,df2)
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey! If this solves your doubt please don't forget to click on that tick mark on the left side. This helps other community members to quickly find the correct answer. Thanks!